# How to make a descending order in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, sorting

I have a list like this

[image]

can you show me the way to descending order by clicking the button up and down like following?

[image]

in firebase and I'm using nodejs

Comment: It's important to post codebase what you have tried, Please read this before asking the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The question is very unclear. What does clicking the button up and down arrow have to do with descending order? If that's a UI, then clicking the down arrow would move that row down in the list. For for example, if you click the up arrow by Charlie, it would move the Charlie row up and above Justin. If that's not what those buttons do, you may want to re-think that functionality. If you want to work with data descending in general, you can either load the data and sort in code or load the data and insert each element at position 0 into an array. That will reverse their order.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort data while querying itself from Firebase,

Something like following.

```
var topUserPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('user-posts/' + myUserId).orderByChild('starCount');
```

Reference: [Sorting and Filtering on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would present the data in descending order per the question? Also, there is no 'starCount' child.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not support outputting data in descending order. What you could do is just reverse the array that you use to hold the data

```
dataArray.reverse()
```

Comment: Why update data in firebase? You can keep the data as it is and reverse the array every-time you need to sort in descending order.